# How to get an image from gridFS in Meteorjs

Tags: mongodb, meteor, gridfs

I am using the gridFS package in MeteorJS.

What system does is upload a product with an image a title, a category and a price. This gets saved in the products collection.

With a template helper I can get a product from the db with it's title {{title}} and price {{price}}. But I'm stuck getting the image using the reference in de the product document.

Can anyone help me with that?

```
    <template name="product">
        <div class="small-6 medium-3 columns end">
                <div class="product-container">
                    <div class="image-container">
                        {{#with image}}
                            <img src="{{this.url}}" class="product-image" alt="" />
                        {{/with}}
                    </div>
                    <div class="product-details">
                        <div class="product-title">
                            <a href="/productpage">{{title}}</a>
                        </div>
                        <div class="product-price">
                            {{price}}
                        </div>
                        <div class="product-buttons">
                            <span class="icon-heart"></span>
                            <span class="icon-repost"></span>
                            <span class="icon-plus"></span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
    </template>
```

```
    <template name="home">
    {{#each products}}
        {{> product}}
    {{/each}}
    </template>
```

```
    Products = new Mongo.Collection("products");

        var productImagesStore = new FS.Store.FileSystem('productImages', {
            path: '~/uploads/full'
        });

        productImages = new FS.Collection('productImages', {
            stores: [productImagesStore]
        });
        productImages.allow({
            insert: function () {
                return true;
            },
            update: function () {
                return true;
            },
            remove: function () {
                return true;
            },
            download: function () {
                return true;
            }
        });


    if (Meteor.isClient) {
          // This code only runs on the client
          Template.home.helpers({
            products: function () {
                return Products.find({});
            },
            image:function(){
                return productImages.findOne({'metadata.productId':this._id})
            }
          });

          Template.add.helpers({
            categories: function(){
                return categories.find({});
            }
          });


        Template.add.events({
            "submit form": function(event, template) {
                event.preventDefault();

                var file = $('#file').get(0).files[0],
                fsFile = new FS.File(file),
                productData = {
                    title:$('#title').val(),
                    price:$('#price').val(),
                    category:$('#category').val()
                }

                Products.insert(productData,function(err,result){
                    if(!err){
                        fsFile.metadata = {
                            productId:result, //we use metadata to refer the recent object id with the product images
                        }
                        productImages.insert(fsFile,function(err,result){
                            if(!err){
                                console.log("New images inserted")
                            }
                        });
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can store the reference on the productImages collection like this.

```
 var file = $('#file').get(0).files[0],
     fsFile = new FS.File(file),
     productData = {
       title:$('#title').val(),
       price:$('#price').val(),
       category:$('#category').val()
                }
    Products.insert(productData,function(err,result){
               if(!err){
                 fsFile.metadata = {
                        productId:result, //we use metadata to refer the recent object id with the product images
                    }
                 productImages.insert(fsFile,function(err,result){
                  if(!err){
                     console.log("New images inserted")
                    }
                  });
                 }
               });
```

This is the same insert but a little bit more cleaner

Now you can use the helper and the `this` context like this.

**HTML**

```
{{#each products}}
   {{title}}
   {{price}}
    {{#with image}}
      IMG URL:{{this.url}}
      <img src="{{this.url}}" />
    {{/with}}
 {{/each}}
```

**JS(Helpers)**

```
Template.example.helpers({
  products:function(){
   return Products.find()
  },
   image:function(){
   return productImages.findOne({'metadata.productId':this._id})
   }
})
```

Comment: hey appreciate it. but it still doesn't work. I don't get any errors though. I've updated my code. I found out that I have both gridFS and cfs:filesystem installed, would that matter?

Comment: not really are you sure that the images are getting inserted and saved on the ~/uploads/full path? if you run productImages.fetch() what you get?

Comment: yes I checked the file system the images are stored in the right path. Where do I run that? (quite new to JS & meteor)  I've run it in the console but that runs an error.

Comment: on the console run productImages.find().fetch(); if you get something like "productImages" don't exists, did you remove the insecure package? if yes, you have the publish/subscribe functions?

Comment: when I run that I get an array with FS.File

Comment: nice click on 1 of the objects and check the metadata field on the last image you upload